# How to select correct gradle version in React Native

Tags: react-native, gradle

I never upgraded my gradle since 4.3 and now i decided to upgrade my libs. Firstly i updated my react native version to 0.63. And now thinking to upgrade gradle as well. But cannot decide which version to upgrade?

Is there any docs for that, or always it should be updated to latest version?

EDIT: Got these errors below while updating

[image]

Comment: you can use 6.4 version for RN 0.6X. or above version its stable

Comment: thank you, but got the error above while trying to update it

Comment: try this answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53448758/11776310

Comment: i dont even have implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
in my build.gradle

Comment: Check your build.gradle file in android folder and find  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.X") and replace  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")

Comment: its was 4.0.0... i replaced it with 3.5.3 now  Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50.

Comment: its your new Project or migrate old to latest RN?

Comment: old to latesst RN, it was started with 0.59xx

Comment: Follow this": https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.9&to=0.62.2