# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fast-image'

Tags: react-native, kotlin

I am trying to run this app, but  I am getting below error, Could you please guide me to fix it?

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fast-image'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-fast-image:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.4.0       
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.4.0  
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools:common:26.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.4.0 > com.android.tools:repository:26.4.0
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.21/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.pom'.    
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.21.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.4.0
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.4.0
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.21.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.21/kotlin-reflect-1.3.21.pom'.      
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.21/kotlin-reflect-1.3.21.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04
         project :react-native-fast-image > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 > com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta04
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.0/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.0/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Below is a simulation of the error I am having:

[Screen shot of error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIshJ.png)

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share some information about how to reproduce the problem, ideally a [mcve]?  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: But maybe this is related: [How to resolve error "Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7..." when building in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53448450/3744182).